# Karma test with phantomjs fails with ngIf

Tags: angular, phantomjs, integration-testing, karma-jasmine

I have an angular-cli project.

The html I want to test looks like this:

```
<div *ngIf="!isMobile" class="shop-description">
  {{ description }}
</div>
<div class="shop-link">
  <span>
    {{ link}}
  </span>
</div>
```

The tests look like this:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ShopItemComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.shop = ShopServiceMock.shops[0];
    component.isMobile = false;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
  it('should have a title', () => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        const el = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
        expect(el.querySelector('div.shop-title>span').innerText).toContain('test');
    });

  it('should have a description', () => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        const el = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
        expect(el.querySelector('div.shop-description').innerText).toContain('love');
    });
```

With the command '**ng test**' everything passes, no problem.

With '**npm run test:phantomjs -- --code-coverage**' the first test on the title element passes but the test on description fails with:

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating
>   'el.querySelector('div.shop-description').innerText')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a *ngIf that is setting the element to not exist. 
This is why you should first set the isMobile to false before looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

I moved `component.isMobile = false;` inside `it('should...` and it removed the error.

I'm not sure why this but if someone has an explanation, I am open for ideas.